# Create a Class at run time and use it in .Net?

Tags: .net, c, sql-server, reflection, reflection.emit

I want to create Models at run time based on theirs properties and fields type that stored on SQL Server.

for example i have a table named test

```
UserName varchar(50) not null,
Password varchar(4) not null,
IsAdmin bit not null
```

So i have to create this model at runtime

```
public class Test
{
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    public string Password{get;set;}
    public bool IsAdmin{get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Easiest ways are to use either a *PropertyBag* implementation or the *Decorator Pattern*. Is there a reason why both of these are unsuitable for your needs? It is much more work to actually compile code at run time, though it can be done.

Comment: Could you explain how exactly would you use the class?

Comment: n first window User can Select Field of tables in DB after then I create this table in Sql Server and in other form, User can show list of all tables and show All data of an specified table,so I should create Domain Classes based on Created table by user to I can Bind list of Data on the table to show it via GridView in WPF App and so on...

Comment: Sounds like you need to rewire EF to generate your model runtime, shouldn't be too difficult to pull off, look at EF7 git

Comment: I think, you're trying to solve a problem that can be easier solved by using metadata and ADO.NET

Comment: T.S No my solution don't similar ado or meta data solutions...

Comment: I don't think EF can be solve this solution...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is both complicated and error prone. Generating code at runtime is usually a BAD idea. This kind of design usually merely hides deeper problems within the code base, the architecture and the implementation of the design.

That being said, it is possible to declare [`dynamic`variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) since .NET 4.0. You could use a collection of these (a list or a dictionary) to store them instead of generating whole classes.

Comment: Yes I agree.But in my solution I don't have any table or schema, you know, My Sql Schema also will be created at run time by End User, so i need create my module at run time once End User created Sql Schema...

Comment: In first window User can Select Field of tables in DB after then I create this table in Sql Server and in other form, User can show list of all tables and show All data of an specified table,so I should create Domain Classes based on Created table by user to I can Bind list of Data on the table to show it via GridView in WPF App and so on...